# If value in Column E2 is “Purchase” then Sum C2:F2 else Substract C2:F2

Tags: excel

I am trying to create an inventory sheet and trying to write a formula. Could anyone help me out.

If value in Column E2 is “Purchase” then Sum C2 and F2 else Substract C2and F2

Need a formula for this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `=IF(E2="Purchase"; C2+F2; C2-F2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work fine for you.

```
  =if(E2="Purchase",SUM(C2,F2),C2-F2)
```

Comment: Another help i need. Also, i want the value which comes using this formula to be automatically copied to column C2. What should I do?

Comment: @KaviThePoetry-ArtProject in C2 type =E2  . If someone provides an answer that works for you click the up arrow next to it to signify you've accepted it by the way.

Comment: Thank you. Got stuck with another sheet. Please help. If value in Column D2 is “Purchase” then Sum C2 and E2 else Substract C2 and E2. At the same time as soon as the formula is applied, I want the formula result (F2 in my case) to get copied to C2 and values in E 2 to change to zero automatically. 

Thank you.

Comment: @KaviThePoetry-ArtProject Please make a sincere attempt to learn some of the formulae used. Start with this: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2

Comment: Thank you for your support and the link. I need to sincerely learn excel. I need to send this sheet urgently to my boss . Request you to help me on this.

Comment: @KaviThePoetry-ArtProject Your question is impossible. You want a formula in F2 to be based upon C2 and E2 yet you want C2 and E2 to change based on the results of F2. This is a circular dependency and cannot be calculated.

Comment: Thank you for your help.